# What is wrong with my Python Ctypes structures?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm having a problem with my structure generation to allow the use of a c Library within Python - I'm hoping someone can point out the errors in my code.

C Prototype:

```
const char *DSpotterVerInfo(char *lpchLicenseFile, VerInfo *lpVerInfo, INT *lpnErr);
```

C Struct Definition:

```
typedef struct _VerInfo
{
    const char *SDKName;
    const char *SDKVersion;
    const char *SDKType;
    const char *Date;
    const char *LType;
    BOOL  bTrialVersion;
} VerInfo;
```

My code:

```
class DSVerInfo(ctypes.Structure):
  # This works (at least no ugly errors, but I can't get to the structure data..)
  #_fields_ = [('Name',ctypes.c_char_p)]


  # This defintion causes an error and a segdump
  _fields_ = [ \
                 ('Name', ctypes.c_char_p), \
                 ('Version', ctypes.c_char_p), \
                 ('SDKType', ctypes.c_char_p), \
                 ('Date', ctypes.c_char_p), \
                 ('LicType', ctypes.c_char_p), \
                 ('Trial', ctypes.c_bool) \
              ]

  def __init__(self):
    self.Name = cast(ctypes.create_string_buffer(str.encode("")),ctypes.c_char_p)
    self.Version = cast(ctypes.create_string_buffer(str.encode("")),ctypes.c_char_p)
    self.SDKType = cast(ctypes.create_string_buffer(str.encode("")),ctypes.c_char_p)
    self.Date = cast(ctypes.create_string_buffer(str.encode("")),ctypes.c_char_p)
    self.LicType = cast(ctypes.create_string_buffer(str.encode("")),ctypes.c_char_p)
    self.Trial = c_bool()


libc.MyLibVerInfo.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,DSVerInfo,ctypes.POINTER(c_int))

err_no = ctypes.c_int()
Lic_ct = ctypes.create_string_buffer(str.encode(License_file))
VerInfo = DSVerInfo()

result = libc.DSpotterVerInfo(Lic_ct,VerInfo,err_no)

print("Result:\n",result.decode('utf-8'),"Error No:", err_no.value)
print("Version Size: ", sizeof(VerInfo))
print(VerInfo)  #Not really any use.. just an object until I can use VerInfo.x
```

Here is a sample of the output when it fails (from the print of the errorNo):

```
 Error No: 155394711
-155394711
Version Size:  48
<__main__.DSVerInfo object at 0x1093287c0>

Done
Segmentation fault: 11
f01898e9b5db0000:Test rpm$
```

**Solution to Question:**

From Mark's comment above the problem in the code is that I was not passing DSVerInfo as a pointer. Update the line calling the C funciton to the following and everything works as expected.

```
# Non-working code:
#libc.DSpotterVerInfo.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,DSVerInfo,ctypes.POINTER(c_int))

#Working code (I had missed that I should be passsing a pointer to DSVerInfo)
libc.DSpotterVerInfo.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,POINTER(DSVerInfo),ctypes.POINTER(c_int))
```

Comment: You mention errors, but never actually showed us any error messages.  That makes it pretty much impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: I added the output.. not much more help than the comments in my code unfortunately.

Comment: What is the prototype of the C function you are trying to call? What are its expected inputs and outputs?  The only issue with the structure definition is `BOOL` is typically defined as `int` in C (`c_int` or `ctypes.wintypes.BOOL` in Python), but the problem is how is the function called correctly?

Comment: Ideally show us how to correctly call the function from C.

Comment: The C function definition is: 
const char *DSpotterVerInfo(char *lpchLicenseFile, VerInfo *lpVerInfo, INT *lpnErr);

Comment: Yes, but how is it used?  What are the expected inputs and outputs?  You're using it incorrectly to get the segfault, but that doesn't tell us the correct use.  Is the first parameter only an input?  Are the 2nd and 3rd parameters written to as outputs? 
 Are you repsonsible for allocating the buffers pointed to by the `lpVerInfo` fields?  show it properly called from C and it is easy to port to Python.

Comment: The function expects pointers as arguments - have you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you need.  Here's a sample implementation of the function call:

test.c

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _VerInfo
{
    const char *SDKName;
    const char *SDKVersion;
    const char *SDKType;
    const char *Date;
    const char *LType;
    BOOL  bTrialVersion;
} VerInfo;

__declspec(dllexport)
const char *DSpotterVerInfo(char *lpchLicenseFile, VerInfo *lpVerInfo, INT *lpnErr) {
    printf("LicenseFile = %s\n", lpchLicenseFile);
    lpVerInfo->SDKName = "SDKName";
    lpVerInfo->SDKVersion = "SDKVersion";
    lpVerInfo->SDKType = "SDKType";
    lpVerInfo->Date = "Date";
    lpVerInfo->LType = "LType";
    lpVerInfo->bTrialVersion = TRUE;
    *lpnErr = 123;
    return "something";
}
```

To call it:

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

class DSVerInfo(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('Name', ct.c_char_p),
                ('Version', ct.c_char_p),
                ('SDKType', ct.c_char_p),
                ('Date', ct.c_char_p),
                ('LicType', ct.c_char_p),
                ('Trial', w.BOOL)]     # c_bool is only 1 byte, Windows BOOL is 4 bytes.

    # Your __init__ is unnecessary.  ctypes inits to null/zero by default
    # and create_string_buffer is only needed if the C function needs
    # pre-allocated buffer to write to.  Since your structure had const
    # char* parameters that wasn't required and pointers to null strings
    # wouldn't be a very big buffer anyway :^)

    # Helper function to print this structure.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'DSVerInfo({self.Name!r}, {self.Version!r}, {self.SDKType!r}, {self.Date!r}, {self.LicType!r}, {self.Trial!r})'
    
dll = ct.CDLL('./test')

# Make sure to use the correct function name and declare both .argtypes and .restype.
dll.DSpotterVerInfo.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,ct.POINTER(DSVerInfo),ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)
dll.DSpotterVerInfo.restype = ct.c_char_p

err_no = ct.c_int()
Lic_ct = b'licensefile'
VerInfo = DSVerInfo()

result = dll.DSpotterVerInfo(Lic_ct, ct.byref(VerInfo), ct.byref(err_no))

print('Result:', result.decode())
print('Error No:', err_no.value)
print('Version Size: ', ct.sizeof(VerInfo))
print(VerInfo)
```

Output:

```
LicenseFile = licensefile
Result: something
Error No: 123
Version Size:  48
DSVerInfo(b'SDKName', b'SDKVersion', b'SDKType', b'Date', b'LType', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks - I am on MacOS, so I had the correct BOOL definition, but your code pointed out I should be passing DSVerInfo as a Pointer, when I wasn't. Changing that fixed my problem!